# How to prevent Javascript from increasing increment by more than one?

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend

The way my code is supposed to work is that when the correct answer button is selected, it should re-run the code and add +1 to the index so that the questions are updated (because this index is used to access a list of questions). The problem is that it is increasing the index by more than 1. I read somewhere that it is tricky using event listeners because of this (although I don't know if this is 100% the reason). What is wrong with my code? Please see below:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// this query selector selects buttons that are used as part of a quiz
let ansbtnpress = document.querySelectorAll(".ansbtn")    
for (let i = 0; i < ansbtnpress.length; i += 1) {
      ansbtnpress[i].addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);

      function checkAnswer() {

        if (ansbtnpress[i].innerHTML == questions[index].correct) {
          //to show answer is correct
          ansbtnpress[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
          //function to revert colour of button back to normal from green
          function revertBtnColour2() {
            ansbtnpress[i].style.backgroundColor = '#F0F0F0';
          }
          //if the answer is correct, then revert button colour, increment the index by 1, and run the quizcontent (which is the entire function) again  
          if (ansbtnpress[i].style.backgroundColor = "green") {
            setTimeout(revertBtnColour2, 200)
            setTimeout(quizcontent, 1000)
            setTimeout(increaseindex, 950);

          }

          function increaseindex() {
            index++;
          }

          // below this part of code doesn't really matter

        } else {
          ansbtnpress[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";

          function revertBtnColour() {
            ansbtnpress[i].style.backgroundColor = '#F0F0F0';
          }
          if (ansbtnpress[i].style.backgroundColor = "red") {
            setTimeout(revertBtnColour, 200)
          }
          hintMessage.style.display = "inline"

        }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

I console.log the index number to see if it increments by 1 and it doesn't. It starts off at 0, then 1, then 3, then 7, then 15. Why is it not only increasing by 1? And what is the solution to achieve this desired result?

EDIT:
This is the total code in the quizcontent function:

```
window.onload= function quizcontent(){
console.log(index)
    
modal.style.display = "block";
hintMessage.style.display = "none";

    questionText.innerHTML = questions[index].question;
    answerA.innerHTML = questions[index].choiceA;
    answerB.innerHTML = questions[index].choiceB;
    answerC.innerHTML = questions[index].choiceC;
    answerD.innerHTML = questions[index].choiceD;
    hintMessage.innerHTML = questions[index].hint;


    if (questions[index].choiceA == null) {
        answerA.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        answerA.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if (questions[index].choiceB == null) {
        answerB.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        answerB.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if (questions[index].choiceC == null) {
        answerC.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        answerC.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if (questions[index].choiceD == null) {
        answerD.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        answerD.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

//code provided by imvain2 below
    function resetEl(el) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            el.classList.remove("correct")
            el.classList.remove("incorrect")
        }, 200)

    }

    function checkAnswer(el) {
        if (el.innerHTML === questions[index].correct) {
            el.classList.add("correct")

            resetEl(el)
            setTimeout(quizcontent, 1000)
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (index === questions.length - 1) {
                    index = 0;
                } else {
                    index++
                }
            }, 950);

        } else {
            el.classList.add("incorrect")
            resetEl(el)
        }
    }

    document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let el = e.target;
        if (el.classList.contains("ansbtn")) {
            checkAnswer(el);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you share mock data or reproducible example? what is **ansbtnpress**?

Comment: I've added the query selector for the buttons at the top. ansbtnpress is the query selector that selects buttons used as part of a quiz.

Answer (score 0):

I overwrote your code to clean it up a bit.

First, instead of recreating the same functions over and over again in a loop, I create a single function that accepts the element as a parameter. Then I delegated the click handler to the body instead of each button. Delegation removes the need of the loop. Also instead of relying on background color inline CSS, I'm adding/removing classes for incorrect and correct.

```js
let question = document.querySelector(".question");
let questions = [{
    "correct": "A",
    "question": "First letter of the alphabet"
  },{
    "correct": "B",
    "question": "Second letter of the alphabet"
  }],
  index = 0;

function quizcontent() {
  question.innerText = questions[index].question
}

function resetEl(el) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    el.classList.remove("correct")
    el.classList.remove("incorrect")
  }, 200)

}

function checkAnswer(el) {
  if (el.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == questions[index].correct.toLowerCase()) {
    el.classList.add("correct")

    resetEl(el)
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (index == questions.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
      } else {
        index++
      }
      quizcontent();
    }, 950);

  } else {
    el.classList.add("incorrect")
    resetEl(el)
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if (el.classList.contains("ansbtn")) {
    checkAnswer(el);
  }
});

quizcontent();
```

```css
.correct {
  background-color: green;
}

.incorrect {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="question"></div>
<button class="ansbtn">A</button>
<button class="ansbtn">B</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for making the code more organised and clean. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same issue where the index is being incremented by more than 1 after the first correct click (I should have 10 questions displayed one after another, but because the index is higher than it should be I end up skipping questions, if that makes sense).

Comment: @SFleevo I made some tweaks to my answer but I can't duplicate your problem. What is the code in **quizcontent**?

Comment: I've just added the code for the quizcontent  at the end of my post above.